# What is the general theory that describes the interactions between strings?

Tags: string-theory, second-quantization, string-field-theory

What is the general theory that describes the interactions between strings? I mean the basic object in the theory is (closed) string and they have interactions among them. The string theory, as I learned now (I am far from an expert!), describes only one string. Can anyone recommend a reference of such a theory?

Answer (score 1):

String theory is the theory of the propagation **and** interaction of strings.
Any textbook on String theory will have several chapters devoted to the calculation of string scattering amplitudes.

Answer (score 0):

string theory does not describe only one string, quite the opposite, each particle is a string. The theory also describe the  interactions between particles, and so, between strings.

Comment: Thank you for your inspiration. Can you tell me a reference of the above formulism? Especially about the gauge theory.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have pointed out already, String theory describes not only one string, the basic objects are open and closed strings, also there are some other fundamental ones such as D-branes. As a firrst book to read I would recommend Zwiebach, "A first course in String Theory".